# Firebase cloud messaging Each then() should return a value or throw promise/always-return

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a cloud function for firebase for my android app. I can't resolve this error. I am a complete newbie.

> 29:73  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/comment')
 .onWrite((change, context) => {

     // get user ids
     const reciever_id = context.params.reciever_id;
     const sender_id = context.params.sender_id;
     const comment = context.params.comment;
     const object_id = context.params.object_id;
     const objecttype = context.params.objecttype;

     //get the token of reciever 
     return admin.database().ref("/users/" + reciever_id).once('value').then(snap => {
         const token = snap.child("token").val();
         // Create a payload
         var payload = {
             data: {
                 data_type: "direct_message",
                 title: "Comment from" + sender_id,
                 comment: comment,
                 object_id: object_id,
                 objecttype: objecttype,
             }
         };

         // Sent To device with token Id : THIS IS LINE 29
         return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload).then(response => {
             console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);})
            .catch(error => {console.log("Error:", error); });

});  // token

}); // onWrite
```

Comment: If you google that error message, do the search results come up with any helpful information about how best to work with promises?

Comment: deployment worked now!  you can see the answer..!
I was following a tutorial & my function was was uploaded to firebase but it was log was giving an error so i deleted it and start the process of cloud function again.. then i got error on deployment before it wasn't the case..I was confused because the same code was uploaded before..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT worked I just changed this

```
    // Sent To device with token Id
         return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload).then(result => {
            return console.log("Successfully sent message:", result);
         })
```